# Confused In Compilers

Tags: c++, ide

I am a beginner in C++
I am learning this language
Yesterday only i raised a query to which i got many answer everyone was saying i am coding in old language so i decided to learn again from book **Programming Principles and practise using C++** By *Bjarne Stroustrup*
Here is my Query i asked yesterday: [Nead Help To Sort File in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45180649/nead-help-to-sort-file-in-c)
Now I am too much confused in Compilers
I downloaded different software
Visual Studio 2017 , Code:: block .
Now i dont know which compiler i should use.
Even i am not able to run this simple programme from first chapter

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

    int main() 
    {
    cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    return 0; 
    }
```

Here is the List of Compiler My PC have :
[Compiler List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNALI.jpg)

Please help me in this case.
I am too confused in compilers now.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is here. You don't need multiple compilers. You need one that works. Visual Studio is fine. Just use that unless you have some compelling reason not to.

Comment: It's not clear what `std_lib_facilities.h` is or why that's here. If that's missing then that's your problem. Note when asking a question on Stack Overflow it's always best to post the **exact** error messages you're getting.

Comment: BTW you don't have all those compilers

Comment: The header file you are missing [is available here](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/PPP2code/std_lib_facilities.h).

Comment: As long as whatever you use supports C++14 you should be fine. Just pick something you lile. Clang, gcc or Visual C++, doesn't really matter; they are all fine compilers.

Comment: Visual Studio has one of the best debuggers, if not the best debugger, available. You want a good debugger. Learning to use it will save you so much time it's disheartening to think some beginning programmers don't know they exist. I'd stick to Visual Studio for now.

Comment: Read Appendix C: Getting Started with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Use Code:Blocks this the one of the best compiler for c and c++. Visual stdio is also one of them but the interface gives us some difficulties for the beginners.